# Ajax and jquery code not sure how it works

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

someone helped me out doing some ajax and jquery code, I'm implementing new code but I got stuck trying to do an effect. Well, I have an Ajax call that go to an API and return 11 divs and display the divs fine, what I want to do is to slideDown the div number 11 so I can get the effect of something new pushing down the old stuff, my div 11 has a class "push-old-divs" my problem here is that I don't know how to get that div from the Ajax return "msg". How to show all the divs exept the one with class "push-old-divs" and then prepend that div.

```
        $.ajax({
          url: "lead-activity.php?limit=0&limit_sup="+(limit+new_leads)+ "&newleadslast=" + new_leads,
            success: function(msg){ 
              $("#div_container_leads").html('<div id="div_before_new"></div>'+msg+'<div id="div_before_more"></div>');
            }
        });
```

Comment: First, what does the ajax return msg look like?

Comment: Second, you need to call the `.slideDown()` function in the Ajax success.

Comment: The JSON response looks something like this: <div id="div1">a</div>  <div id="div2">b</div>....<div id="div11" class="push-old-divs">m</div>

Answer (score 0):

So I understand your question, you have 11 divs, and you want to insert a div from the ajax msg between div#10 and div#11?

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/mnxWg/

It uses `.hide(1000)`, which slides up, but you can use the slideUp method as well

Comment: Just a heads up, this should be in the comment section, not as an answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment

Comment: My msg returns 11 divs, div 1, div2, div3... but I just want to display 10 divs and hide the div11 which has a class "push-old-divs", once I display the 10 divs I want to display div11 but doing a slideDown effect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would first put `display:none;` on the div with the class 'push-old-divs' in your php so when it loads it is originally hidden

Then modify your ajax success function like so

```
$.ajax({
    url: "lead-activity.php?limit=0&limit_sup="+(limit+new_leads)+ "&newleadslast=" + new_leads,
    success: function(msg){

        $("#div_container_leads").html('<div id="div_before_new"></div>'+msg+'<div id="div_before_more"></div>');
        $('.push-old-divs').slideDown(500);


    }
});
```